# Is there a way to keep all the query parameters in URL when changing language by Polylang plugin?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

When setting queries in the URL for posts on a page then changing the language by polylang plugin it resets the link and gets rid of the parameters and queries. The page is built on Wordpress on a custom theme I develop. `./en/projects/?tag_kem_en%5B%5D=three-springs` gets changed to `./projekty/`
I change the language with this code:
`pll_the_languages($args);`

Answer (score 8):

You can include the query parameters by adapting the URL that Polylang provides though `pll_the_languages()`.

I got it to work using this code snippet.

```
/**
 * Filter the translation url of the current page before Polylang caches it.
 *
 * @param null|string $url The translation url, null if none was found.
 */
function url_query_string( $url ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
        return $url . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'pll_the_language_link', 'url_query_string' );
```

P.s Make sure to prefix the function or use namespaces.